# Find the Least count number and then divide that number to specific remaing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to check each value of text box value as a localstorage id and get the specifiv value of that id and then check that value is equal to or greater then a specific value in my example the value local storage's `Total_thrisholdvalue1` value

[In this example the if condition works](http://jsfiddle.net/chsgf50t/21/)

[Expecting some thing in else condition](http://jsfiddle.net/chsgf50t/22/)

My problem is while checking if the value is not grater then or equals to then on else condition by using the value of text box's on each condition it should find least number by using the above textbox value as the localstorage id as it is doing in if condition then divide the number for the remaining localstorage data value and check if the value match's the `Total_thrisholdvalue1`  if matches then alert that value else eliminate another most least untill the value is equal to or greater then `Total_thrisholdvalue1`

JS:

```
    localStorage.setItem('Total_thrisholdvalue1','4');
    localStorage.setItem('A9AH98','3');
    localStorage.setItem('16B9BH','2'); localStorage.setItem('CC9GHF','4'); 
localStorage.setItem('A9D9G5','5');


$(".candidateid").each(function () {
    var data = $(this).val();
    var candidates_count = localStorage.getItem(data);
    var Total_thrisholdvalue = localStorage.getItem('Total_thrisholdvalue1');

    if (candidates_count >= Total_thrisholdvalue) {

        alert(data );
    } else {

    }
});
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" value="A9AH98" class="candidateid">
<input type="text" value="16B9BH" class="candidateid">
<input type="text" value="CC9GHF" class="candidateid">
<input type="text" value="A9D9G5" class="candidateid">
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Please formulate your question in normal English. Preferably in shorter sentences.

Comment: @wintvelt sorry by using each value of textbox as localstorage ima getting the values of each localstorage id's data and check the each value with the `Total_thrisholdvalue` then the problem is hear after checking if none of the values are greater then `Total_thrisholdvalue` then by using the same texbox as localstorage id and on fetch check whose number is less then divide the localstorage data of last and split then to others remaining who has and then check who has the the value greater then  `Total_thrisholdvalue` if yes alert that value else repeat the same till last by reducing the one

Answer (score 0):

The values retrieved from `localStorage` are `strings`, so the `>` operator won't work as you might expect. Parse them to ints first:

```
var candidatesCount = parseint(localStorage.getItem(data), 10);
var totalThresholdvalue = parseint(localStorage.getItem('Total_thrisholdvalue1'), 10);

if (candidatesCount > totalThresholdvalue) {
   // etc.
}
```